# Regular expression to find a sequence of numbers before multiple patterns, into a new column (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, spyder

Here is my **sample data**:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
  
cars = pd.DataFrame({'Engine Information': {0: 'Honda 2.4L 4 cylinder 190 hp 162 ft-lbs',
          1: 'Aston Martin 4.7L 8 cylinder 420 hp 346 ft-lbs',
          2: 'Dodge 5.7L 8 Cylinder 390hp 407 ft-lbs',
          3: 'MINI 1.6L 4 Cylinder 118 hp 114 ft-lbs',
          4: 'Ford 5.0L 8 Cylinder 360hp 380 ft-lbs FFV',
          5: 'GMC 6.0L 8 Cylinder 352 hp 382 ft-lbs'},
         'HP': {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None}})
```

Here is my **desired output**:

[image]

I have created a new column called 'HP' where I want to extract the horsepower figure from the original column ('Engine Information')

Here is the **code I have tried to do this**:

```
cars['HP'] = cars['Engine Information'].apply(lambda x: re.match(r'\\d+(?=\\shp|hp)', str(x)))
```

The idea is I want to regex match the pattern: 'a sequence of numbers that come before either 'hp' or ' hp'. This is because some of the cells have no 'space' in between the number and 'hp' as showed in  my example.

I'm sure the regex is correct, because I have successfully done a similar process in R. However, I have tried functions such as `str.extract`, `re.findall`, `re.search`, `re.match`. Either returning errors or 'None' values (as shown in the sample). So here I am a bit lost.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is there two "\" in front of "s"? \d+(?=\\shp|hp). When removing one, it matches all hp values correctly: https://regex101.com/r/Aeh0LX/1

Comment: `r'\\d+(?=\\shp|hp)'` ==> `r'\d+(?=\shp|hp)'` or `'\\d+(?=\\shp|hp)'`

Comment: Tried both of these solutions, still returns 'None' values in my table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
cars['HP'] = cars['Engine Information'].str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*hp\b', flags=re.I)
```

**Details**

- `(\d+)\s*hp\b` - matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits, then just matches 0 or more whitespaces (`\s*`) and `hp` (in a case insensitive way due to `flags=re.I`) as a whole word (since `\b` marks a word boundary)
- `str.extract` only returns the captured value if there is a capturing group in the pattern, so the `hp` and whitespaces are not part of the result.

Python demo results:

```
>>> cars
                               Engine Information   HP
0         Honda 2.4L 4 cylinder 190 hp 162 ft-lbs  190
1  Aston Martin 4.7L 8 cylinder 420 hp 346 ft-lbs  420
2          Dodge 5.7L 8 Cylinder 390hp 407 ft-lbs  390
3          MINI 1.6L 4 Cylinder 118 hp 114 ft-lbs  118
4       Ford 5.0L 8 Cylinder 360hp 380 ft-lbs FFV  360
5           GMC 6.0L 8 Cylinder 352 hp 382 ft-lbs  352
```

Comment: Also, see [this Python demo online](https://repl.it/repls/RipeThunderousCubase#main.py).

Comment: At first this returned me: `TypeError: extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'` , however I removed the 'extract' argument and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @k3b Strange, see the docs: "*`expand`* : ***bool, default True***
*If True, return DataFrame with one column per capture group. If False, return a Series/Index if there is one capture group or DataFrame if there are multiple capture groups.*"

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

- `re.match` just looks at the beginning of your string, use `re.search` if your pattern may appear anywhere
- don't escape if you use a raw string, i.e. either`'\\d hp'` or `r'\d hp'` - raw strings help your exactly to avoid escaping
- Return the matched group. You just search but do not yield the group found. `re.search(rex, string)` gives you a complex object (a match object) from this you can extract all groups, e.g. `re.search(rex, string)[0]`
- you have to wrap the access in a separate function because you have to check if there was any match before accessing the group. If you don't do that, an exception may stop the apply process right in the middle
- apply is slow; use pandas vectorized functions like extract: `cars['Engine Information'].str.extract(r'(\d+) ?hp')`

Your approach should work with this:

```
def match_horsepower(s):
    m = re.search(r'(\d+) ?hp', s)
    return int(m[1]) if m else None

cars['HP'] = cars['Engine Information'].apply(match_horsepower)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is will get numeric value just before hp, without or with (single or multiple) spaces.

```
r'\d+(?=\s+hp|hp)'
```

You can verify Regex Here: https://regex101.com/r/pXySxm/1

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I still get 'None' values being returned.